# What snitch am I running?

Tags: datastax-enterprise

I recently ran;

```
sudo nodetool describecluster
```

and got the following output;

> Snitch: org.apache.cassandra.locator.DynamicEndpointSnitch

Which confused me because in cassandra.yaml on each of my nodes, I have the following;

```
endpoint_snitch: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch
```

In fact - I can't even see

> DynamicEndpointSnitch

as a valid option in the cassandra.yaml file.

Are the two the same thing?
Am I just misinterpreting the output of nodetool?

As always - Thanks!
-Gavin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cassandra's dynamic snitching feature wraps the snitch specified in the cassandra.yaml file with the DynamicEndpointSnitch. This snitch sorts endpoints by latency with an adapted phi failure detector thus providing a way to select the highest performing nodes for reads.